# Tweaking query to account for an if statement?

Tags: sql, presto

I have a query like below, where based on if the ***original_time*** column is less than or earlier then ***start_time*** then it gives me the first time as time column that is being subtracted from the original time column in the date diff calculated field as below.

The ***table m*** has two time columns, also a ***second_time*** column, is there a way where I can tweak the query below to say based on if the ***t.original_time*** column is less than or earlier than the *start_time* column, then the ***m.first_time*** column is being used in the calculated field, and if the ***t.original_time*** column is > or later than the ***m.start_time*** field, then it will use the m.second_time column in the calculated field? Instead of running this query twice?

```
SELECT t.id,
       t.time,
       m.first_time,
       date_diff('minute',m.first_time, t.original_time) AS Calculation
FROM table t
JOIN table m ON t.id = m.id
WHERE t.original_time < m.start_time
```

Second query I am running is:

```
SELECT t.id,
           t.time,
           m.second_time,
           date_diff('minute',m.second_time, t.original_time) AS Calculation
    FROM table t
    JOIN table m ON t.id = m.id
    WHERE t.original_time > m.start_time
```

Basically instead of running these 2 queries just tweak it to account for both?

Thanks for the time!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need:

Maybe you don't need the Where clause if one of the conditions is less equal or greater equal.

```
SELECT t.id,
       t.time,
       m.first_time,
       m.second_time,
       case 
          when t.original_time < m.start_time then           
            date_diff('minute',m.first_time, t.original_time)
          else
            null
       end as calculation_less,
       case 
          when t.original_time > m.start_time then           
            date_diff('minute',m.second_time, t.original_time)
          else
            null
       end as calculation_greater   
FROM table t
JOIN table m ON t.id = m.id
WHERE t.original_time < m.start_time or 
      t.original_time > m.start_time
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this using [`if`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/conditional.html#if):

```sql
SELECT t.id,
       t.time,
       if(t.original_time < m.start_time, m.first_time, m.second_time),
       date_diff('minute', if(t.original_time < m.start_time, m.first_time, m.second_time), t.original_time) AS Calculation
FROM table t
JOIN table m ON t.id = m.id
WHERE t.original_time <> m.start_time
```

Note that your queries only consider the cases where `t.original_time` and `m.start_time` are not equal to each other, hence the `WHERE` clause in the query above.